# Event binding - Capture variable in a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why it alerts 'two' whether I am clicking on button 'one' or 'two'.

```
<button id="one"> One </button>
<button id="two"> Two </button>

$(function(){
    var some_arg = 'one';
    $("#one").click(function(){
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });

    some_arg = 'two';

    $("#two").click(function(){
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });

});

function my_alert(test){
    alert(test);
}
```

Thanks!

**[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/DRj9S/8/)**

Comment: As you are using `some_arg = 'two';` sequential execution of code.

Comment: some_arg = 'one' before binding my first click event.

Comment: Only event is binded, As soon as it hit `some_arg = 'two';` previous value is overwritten.

Comment: @AntoineCloutier But handler's code is evaluated only once you click, so value equal 'two'

Comment: @AntoineCloutier, you are assigning some_arg = 'one' and then some_arg = 'two'. hence final value for some_arg is "two". change value inside click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you seem to want to use some closures, this could be done like this too:

```
$(function () {
    var some_arg = 'one';
    (function (some_arg) { // some_arg is local, no more referring to outter scoped one
        $("#one").click(function () {
            my_alert(some_arg); 
        });
    })(some_arg);

    some_arg = 'two';
    (function (some_arg) { // some_arg is local, no more referring to outter scoped one
        $("#two").click(function () {
            my_alert(some_arg);
        });
    })(some_arg);
});
```

### --DEMO--

Answer (score 1):

Click events are fired after `some_arg` is set to 'two'

```
$(function(){
    var some_arg = 'one';
    $("#one").click(function(){
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });

    $("#two").click(function(){
        some_arg = 'two';
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DRj9S/9/)

```
$(function(){

    var some_arg;//create a variable

    $("#one").click(function(){
        some_arg = 'one'; // assign 'one' to our variable  some_arg to 
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });



    $("#two").click(function(){
        some_arg = 'two';// assign 'two' to our variable  some_arg to 
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });

});

function my_alert(test){
    alert(test);
}
```

Source: [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var some_arg;
    $("#one").click(function(){
        some_arg = 'one';
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });

    $("#two").click(function(){
        some_arg = 'two';
        my_alert(some_arg);
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm sure the OP would appreciate some sort of explanation, not just code.